# Hide border style on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on something and I want to hide my `border-style` and my `border-color` when I press a button, is that possible? I have it 9 times, so 9 lines. I want to hide them when I click on the button and when I click again it shows them again.

```css
html,
body {
  /* The universe takes up all available space */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* The universe is black */
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sun {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  border-color: orange;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 64px red;
}
#earth {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#mercurius {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#venus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#mars {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#jupiter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#saturnus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#uranus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#neptunes {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#pluto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#mercurius-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: -85px;
  margin-left: -85px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 9s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin-right 9s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin-right 9s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin-right 9s linear infinite;
  animation: spin-right 9s linear infinite;
}
#venus-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  margin-top: -135px;
  margin-left: -135px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
  animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
}
#earth-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  margin-top: -185px;
  margin-left: -185px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 11s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin-right 11s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin-right 11s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin-right 11s linear infinite;
  animation: spin-right 11s linear infinite;
}
#mars-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-top: -235px;
  margin-left: -235px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 12s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin-right 12s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin-right 12s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin-right 12s linear infinite;
  animation: spin-right 12s linear infinite;
}
#jupiter-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 650px;
  height: 650px;
  margin-top: -285px;
  margin-left: -285px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 13s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin-right 13s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin-right 13s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin-right 13s linear infinite;
  animation: spin-right 13s linear infinite;
}
#saturnus-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
  margin-top: -335px;
  margin-left: -335px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
  animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
}
#uranus-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 850px;
  height: 850px;
  margin-top: -385px;
  margin-left: -385px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 15s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin-right 15s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin-right 15s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin-right 15s linear infinite;
  animation: spin-right 15s linear infinite;
}
#neptunes-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 950px;
  height: 950px;
  margin-top: -435px;
  margin-left: -435px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 16s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin-right 16s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin-right 16s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin-right 16s linear infinite;
  animation: spin-right 16s linear infinite;
}
#pluto-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 1050px;
  margin-top: -485px;
  margin-left: -485px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 17s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin-right 17s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin-right 17s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin-right 17s linear infinite;
  animation: spin-right 17s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin-right {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin-right {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<h2 style="color: white; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 50px;">Zoom out for a better view</h2>
<!-- Right below is an image of the sun -->
<img id="sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/v1KUj9f.png">

<!-- Insert the 'earth' on the next line -->
<div id='earth-orbit'>
  <img id="earth" src="http://i.imgur.com/ThNW8nI.png">
</div>

<div id='mercurius-orbit'>
  <img id="mercurius" src="http://i.imgur.com/AHsmibX.png">
</div>

<div id='venus-orbit'>
  <img id="venus" src="http://i.imgur.com/1Jgxg26.png">
</div>

<div id='mars-orbit'>
  <img id="mars" src="http://i.imgur.com/PdoX4P0.png">
</div>

<div id='jupiter-orbit'>
  <img id="jupiter" src="http://i.imgur.com/qF8mGmG.png">
</div>

<div id='saturnus-orbit'>
  <img id="saturnus" src="http://i.imgur.com/CsEIxeq.png">
</div>

<div id='uranus-orbit'>
  <img id="uranus" src="http://i.imgur.com/aIbM21j.png">
</div>

<div id='neptunes-orbit'>
  <img id="neptunes" src="http://i.imgur.com/joA0iCp.png">
</div>

<div id='pluto-orbit'>
  <img id="pluto" src="http://i.imgur.com/qQvhUuF.png">
</div>

<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: All the border-style's and border-color's!

Comment: I would give them classes instead of id's and then separate out the border logic into a class, maybe called .orbit, and toggle the class on click of button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this..

CSS:

```
.borderless {
  border-width: 0 !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#mercurius-orbit').toggleClass('borderless');
    //... for all objects with borders
});
```

Your button:

```
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/1c68fqp0/)** is a working example.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass` as OP has mentioned he wants the effect to be removed when clicked again.

Comment: there's a typo there, it should be `toggleClass` :)

Comment: You sir, are a hero!

Comment: Well.. When uploading it doesn't make any difference but when running the fiddle I do get what I want..

Comment: Maybe you need to add jQuery, https://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/1c68fqp0/1/ you can find the link in this version's HTML

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .cls {
                border-style: dashed;
                border-color: green;
                width: 200px;
                height: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div>Hello Lucafraser!</div>
        <br><br>
        <button id="sh">Hide/Show</button>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#sh").click(function(){
                   $("div").toggleClass("cls");
               })
           })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( "#element").click(function() {
   $(this).css('border', '')
})
```

Comment: @PrakashThiru maybe on 22-06-2025 :P

Comment: `I want to hide them when I click on the button and when I click again it shows them again`. See the question again

Comment: @C0dekid Then comment out those lines on 21-06-2025 :D

Comment: @PrakashThiru haha, see you then :'D. But to be constructive, OP want to `toggle` the border, so technically you are not wrong with hiding the border, but it need to appear again ;)

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the html to use classes instead of ids, modified the css for the same leading to the following js working:

HTML code changes, changed ids to classes. eg: `id="earth-orbit"` changed to `class="earth-orbit orbit js-orbit"`, and `id="earth"` changed to `class="earth"`.

CSS code changes, changed ids to classes, eg: `#earth-orbit` to `.earth-orbit` and moved out the following code from each of the orbit classes to a .orbit class:

```
.orbit {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Added `toggle-orbit` class to button with css:

```
.toggle-orbit {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Then added the following jquery:

```
$('.toggle-orbit').on('click', function () {
   $('.js-orbit').toggleClass('orbit');
});
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5xo2vy65/

Classes are better that id's because then they have less specificity in css and can be overridden with other classes easily.

Comment: Well same here.. When uploading it doesn't make any difference but when running the fiddle I do get what I want..

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
html, body {
/* The universe takes up all available space */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

/* The universe is black */
background-color: black;
overflow: hidden;
}

#sun {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

height: 150px;
width: 150px;
margin-top: -40px;
margin-left: -40px;

border-color: orange;
border-width: 8px;
border-style: solid;
border-radius: 50%;

box-shadow: 0 0 64px red;
}

#earth {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;

height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

#mercurius {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;

height: 30px;
width: 30px;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

#venus {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;

height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

#mars {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;

height: 40px;
width: 40px;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

#jupiter {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;

height: 70px;
width: 70px;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

#saturnus {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;

height: 60px;
width: 60px;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

#uranus {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;

height: 60px;
width: 60px;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

#neptunes {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;

height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

#pluto {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;

height: 30px;
width: 30px;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

#mercurius-orbit {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

width: 250px;
height: 250px;
margin-top: -85px;
margin-left: -85px;

border-width: 2px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-animation: spin-right 9s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: spin-right 9s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: spin-right 9s linear infinite;
-o-animation: spin-right 9s linear infinite;
animation: spin-right 9s linear infinite;
}

#venus-orbit {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

width: 350px;
height: 350px;
margin-top: -135px;
margin-left: -135px;

border-width: 2px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
-o-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
}

#earth-orbit {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

width: 450px;
height: 450px;
margin-top: -185px;
margin-left: -185px;

border-width: 2px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-animation: spin-right 11s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: spin-right 11s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: spin-right 11s linear infinite;
-o-animation: spin-right 11s linear infinite;
animation: spin-right 11s linear infinite;
}

#mars-orbit {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

width: 550px;
height: 550px;
margin-top: -235px;
margin-left: -235px;

border-width: 2px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-animation: spin-right 12s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: spin-right 12s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: spin-right 12s linear infinite;
-o-animation: spin-right 12s linear infinite;
animation: spin-right 12s linear infinite;
}

#jupiter-orbit {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

width: 650px;
height: 650px;
margin-top: -285px;
margin-left: -285px;

border-width: 2px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-animation: spin-right 13s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: spin-right 13s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: spin-right 13s linear infinite;
-o-animation: spin-right 13s linear infinite;
animation: spin-right 13s linear infinite;
}

#saturnus-orbit {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

width: 750px;
height: 750px;
margin-top: -335px;
margin-left: -335px;

border-width: 2px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
-o-animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
}

#uranus-orbit {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

width: 850px;
height: 850px;
margin-top: -385px;
margin-left: -385px;

border-width: 2px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-animation: spin-right 15s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: spin-right 15s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: spin-right 15s linear infinite;
-o-animation: spin-right 15s linear infinite;
animation: spin-right 15s linear infinite;
}

#neptunes-orbit {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

width: 950px;
height: 950px;
margin-top: -435px;
margin-left: -435px;

border-width: 2px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-animation: spin-right 16s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: spin-right 16s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: spin-right 16s linear infinite;
-o-animation: spin-right 16s linear infinite;
animation: spin-right 16s linear infinite;
}

#pluto-orbit {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

width: 1050px;
height: 1050px;
margin-top: -485px;
margin-left: -485px;

border-width: 2px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-animation: spin-right 17s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: spin-right 17s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: spin-right 17s linear infinite;
-o-animation: spin-right 17s linear infinite;
animation: spin-right 17s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin-right {
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}

@keyframes spin-right {
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
</style>
<body>

<h2 style="color: white; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 50px;">Zoom out for a better view</h2>
<!-- Right below is an image of the sun -->
<img id="sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/v1KUj9f.png">

<!-- Insert the 'earth' on the next line -->
<div id='earth-orbit' class="r3">
<img id="earth" src="http://i.imgur.com/ThNW8nI.png">
</div>

<div id='mercurius-orbit' class="r1">
<img id="mercurius" src="http://i.imgur.com/AHsmibX.png">
</div>

<div id='venus-orbit' class="r2">
<img id="venus" src="http://i.imgur.com/1Jgxg26.png">
</div>

<div id='mars-orbit' class="r4">
<img id="mars" src="http://i.imgur.com/PdoX4P0.png">
</div>

<div id='jupiter-orbit' class="r5">
<img id="jupiter" src="http://i.imgur.com/qF8mGmG.png">
</div>

<div id='saturnus-orbit' class="r6">
<img id="saturnus" src="http://i.imgur.com/CsEIxeq.png">
</div>

<div id='uranus-orbit' class="r7">
<img id="uranus" src="http://i.imgur.com/aIbM21j.png">
</div>

<div id='neptunes-orbit' class="r8">
<img id="neptunes" src="http://i.imgur.com/joA0iCp.png">
</div>

<div id='pluto-orbit' class="r9">
<img id="pluto" src="http://i.imgur.com/qQvhUuF.png">
</div>

<button class="border_none">Click</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     var iCnt = 10;

        $(".border_none").click(function(){
            iCnt--;   
                $(".r" + iCnt).css("border","10px dashed #ccc");

            if(iCnt==0){
                for(iCnt=0;iCnt<=10;iCnt++){
                     $(".border_none").click(function(){
                        $(".r" + iCnt).css("border","2px dashed #ccc");
                    }); 
                }
              }

            });




});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```